# Calling a blocking method from Constructor - Java

Tags: java, constructor, blocking

I would like to know if it is a bad idea to call a blocking method from within constructor itself.

I am curious to know if we have any guidelines/rules in such a scenario, that we should never call blocking methods in Constructor.

Basically I am trying to do this:

```
class A
{
    // Many instance variables that is to be initialized on instantiaion
    String tempVar = null;

    public A()
    {
        // Initialize all the instance variables
        tempVar=objectClassB.**callBlockingMethod**(); // this method call would return 
                                                       // some data from ClassB Object
    }

    public static void main(String args ...)
    {
        A a = new A();
        // Or should I call the blocking method call only after instantiation according
        // to any guidelines of Java pertaining to performance ?

        // IMPORTANT: It's only when the blocked method returns value , should the main
        // thread proceed as the object 'a' would be sent for further processing
    }
}
```

PS: Eh ,I'm sorry if my question sounds very basic.

Comment: Please define "blocking" here - are you expecting it to take an indeterminate amount of time? Usually constructors should be fairly simple - you wouldn't want to loop forever listening for TCP connections for example... but it's fine to make some method calls.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet , Thanks much for your quick response.
Yes, I meant "Blocking" here in exactly the same sense as you mentioned.
I am trying to listen for incoming connection over bluetooth , and initialize the "connection" variable by the returning value of the blocking method call.

To be very clear I am trying to do this :
StreamConnection con=notifier.acceptAndOpen(); -> in constructor
// where notifier == of type StreamConnectionNotifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought its better you can create one method like connect () inside the class A. After creating object you can call like

A a = new A()
A.connect()

Inside connect method you define the blocking method 
 StreamConnection con=notifier.acceptAndOpen()
.....

if your blocking call doesn't return in specified time period, you consider some mechanism to recover this scenario

Comment: @"Jojo John"   yeah sure Thanks. So I understand that there is some sort of concerns / performance issue on having this method call on cosntructor. 

Will have it implemented as you suggested , and handle them with Some Threads.